# Memory representation of ASCII control codes in R

Tags: r, string, encoding, escaping

If I write `a <- "\n"` in R, what does R store in memory?

Does it store `0x0A` (line feed character), or does it store `0x5C6E` (literal `\n`)?

Said otherwise, is `cat` that returns the string as it appears in memory, and `print` that reverts back control codes into escape sequences (consistently with first encoding above), or the other way around, that is, `print` that returns the string as it is in memory, and `cat` that interprets escape sequences (consistently with second encoding above)?

I find it confusing because in C "\n" was only a shortcut to write the control codes. So C would write the line feed character `0x0A` in memory. I don't think you would ever get "\n" back from a string in C.

Comment: It stores 0x0A. Same as C (and virtually every other programming language out there).

Comment: @KonradRudolph so `print` gets the string and process it to replace 0x0A with a literal "\n"?

Comment: The comment by @KonradRudolph is essentially the answer but if you want to see run `charToRaw(a)`. The output should be `0a`.

Comment: @robertspierre Yes. REPLs for other interpreted languages tend to do the same, e.g. Python and JavaScript (Node/Chrome/…). I am not entirely sure why they do this but it’s occasionally useful. And it clearly illustrates that *`print()` is not supposed to be used for output in R, even though it is frequently abused for that purpose*.

Comment: @KonradRudolph can you post yours as an answer?

Comment: `\n` is an escaping form. Many high level language (and editors) performs themselves escape in the output. What confuse many people is the output: is it really `\` followed by `n` or just 0x0a? The reasons: tools have bad interface: if they escape, they should display in a more visible way. With modern fonts, that should be easier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a nutshell, R directly stores control characters as raw bytes. That is, `'\n'` is stored internally as `0xA0`. As suggested by SamR in the comment, you can verify this by running `charToRaw()`, which shows you the raw byte buffer:

```
charToRaw('\n')
# [1] 0a
```

In this regard it mirrors essentially every other mainstream programming language.

But like many other language interpreters, R treats string values specially when printing them on the [REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) terminal. That’s why printing the value `'\n'` displays `"\n"` instead of a line break. If you want to display the *value* of strings, you therefore can’t use `print()`.<sup>1</sup> Instead, you need to use either `cat()`, `writeLines()` or, if you want to print to the standard error stream, `message()`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Unless you wrap the value in `noquote()`, but using a proper text output function is generally preferred.